# Windows Phone Bing Maps - How to create dynamic info boxes (tooltips) on pushpin tap

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

Do you guys know of any good tutorial on how to create tooltips dynamicaly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easist ways to create an infobox in Bing Maps for WP is to simply use the MessageBox. This will display your content on top of the map and makes it fit in with the metro styling better. Traditionally, using popup infoboxes on the map for mobile applications makes for a poor user experience.

Answer (score 0):

The basics are in here: http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/building-location-service-apps-windows-phone-7